# How to process column names and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my pandas `DataFrame` with original column names.

```
old_dt_cm1_tt   old_dm_cm1   old_rr_cm2_epf   old_gt
1               3            0                0
2               1            1                5
```

1. Firstly I want to extract all unique variations of `cm`, e.g. in this case `cm1` and `cm2`.
2. After this I want to create a new column per each unique `cm`. In this example there should be 2 new columns.
3. Finally in each new column I should store the total count of non-zero original column values, i.e.

> ```
> old_dt_cm1_tt   old_dm_cm1   old_rr_cm2_epf   old_gt    cm1    cm2    
> 1               3            0                0         2      0        
> 2               1            1                5         2      1
> ```

I implemented the first step as follows:

```
cols = pd.DataFrame(list(df.columns))
ind = [c for c in df.columns if 'cm' in c]
df.ix[:, ind].columns
```

How to proceed with steps 2 and 3, so that the solution is automatic (I don't want to manually define column names `cm1` and `cm2`, because in original data set I might have many `cm` variations.

Comment: this seems a bit more string operation then dataframe stuff, you could set it up to create the new name on `cm` and the character after it?

Comment: [an answer from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring) could help get the character after `cm` for each column.

Comment: @JoeBlack Can be in column `names` twice `strings` starting with `cm`, e.g. `cmd_cm1_aa` ?

Comment: @jezrael: No, it's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
print df
   old_dt_cm1_tt  old_dm_cm1  old_rr_cm2_epf  old_gt
0              1           3               0       0
1              2           1               1       5
```

First you can [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) columns contains string `cm`, so columns without `cm` are removed.

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='cm')
```

Now you can change columns to new values like `cm1`, `cm2`, `cm3`.

```
print [cm for c in df1.columns for cm in c.split('_') if cm[:2] == 'cm']
['cm1', 'cm1', 'cm2']

df1.columns = [cm for c in df1.columns for cm in c.split('_') if cm[:2] == 'cm']
print df1
   cm1  cm1  cm2
0    1    3    0
1    2    1    1
```

Now you can count non - zero values - change `df1` to boolean `DataFrame` and `sum` - `True` are converted to `1` and `False` to `0`. You need count by unique column names - so [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) columns and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) values.

```
df1 = df1.astype(bool)
print df1
    cm1   cm1    cm2
0  True  True  False
1  True  True   True

print df1.groupby(df1.columns, axis=1).sum()
   cm1  cm2
0    2    0
1    2    1
```

You need [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.unique.html) columns, which are added to original `df`:

```
print df1.columns.unique()
['cm1' 'cm2']
```

Last you can add new columns by `df[['cm1','cm2']]` from `groupby` function:

```
df[df1.columns.unique()] = df1.groupby(df1.columns, axis=1).sum()
print df
   old_dt_cm1_tt  old_dm_cm1  old_rr_cm2_epf  old_gt  cm1  cm2
0              1           3               0       0    2    0
1              2           1               1       5    2    1
```

Comment: This is clearly a great method but you need a bit more explanation as I don't know much about pandas and wouldn't be able to use this other then copy-paste which is not all that helpful to the OP in the long run.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I try explain more.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that `[cm for c in df1.columns for cm in c.split('_') if cm[:2] == 'cm']` will raise an error if `cm` is present in a column name more then once (like `cmd_cm1`) where as `['cm'+c[c.index('cm') + 2] for c in df.columns if 'cm' in c]` will only use the first occurrence of the substring.

Comment: Although two methods work on different principles, maybe just don't use list comprehension and add appropriate `break` statements to prevent keeping multiple unique names from a single column.

Comment: Thank you for checking my code. Now I have to go away. I ask OP if this `strings` like `cmd` can be in column `names`.  If yes, I update answer. If not, no problem.

Comment: Now that I understand what you are doing I see that `df1 = df.filter(regex="cm")` is creating a copy without the need for `df1 = df.copy()`.  But my goodness this is a **wonderful** answer!

Answer (score 0):

Once you know which columns have `cm` in them you can map them (with a `dict`) to the desired new column with an adapted version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12572399/5827215):

```
col_map = {c:'cm'+c[c.index('cm') + len('cm')] for c in ind}
                                   #   ^ if you are hard coding this in you might as well use 2
```

so that instead of the string after `cm` it is cm and the character directly following, in this case it would be:

```
{'old_dm_cm1': 'cm1', 'old_dt_cm1_tt': 'cm1', 'old_rr_cm2_epf': 'cm2'}
```

Then add the new columns to the DataFrame by iterating over the `dict`:

```
for col,new_col in col_map.items():
    if new_col not in df:
        df[new_col] =[int(a!=0) for a in df[col]]
    else:
        df[new_col]+=[int(a!=0) for a in df[col]]
```

note that `int(a!=0)` will simply give `0` if the value is 0 and `1` otherwise.  The only issue with this is because `dict`s are inherently unordered it may be preferable to add the new columns in order according to the values: (like [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/5827215))

```
import operator

for col,new_col in sorted(col_map.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    if new_col in df:
        df[new_col]+=[int(a!=0) for a in df[col]]
    else:
        df[new_col] =[int(a!=0) for a in df[col]]
```

to ensure the new columns are inserted in order.