# [Python][Str formating] How can i find next indexnumber in using 'Find'

Tags: python, find

Here is a sentence

```
"[come]and[joy]"
```

I want to get a text in Second `"[ ]"`
So i'll use a

```
 Mid(10,14)
```

For getting indexnumber (10,14),
I wrote next code

```
sentense.findall('[')[1]
```

But, occurred error

```
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findall'
```

If i use the below code

```
 sentense.find('[')
```

it return just first index number of '['  = 0
How can i get a second index number of '['  = 10?

It must be not using like this  sentense.find('[',1),
It will be possible to search sencond, or third, any Next level

please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a string after a specific substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring)

Answer (score 0):

To get the indices of all occurrences of `[` in a string:

```
>>> sentence = "[come] and[joy]"
>>> [i for i,c in enumerate(sentence) if c=='[']
[0, 10]
```

To extract the strings (without using re):

```
>>> start = [i+1 for i,c in enumerate(sentence) if c=='[']
>>> end = [i for i,c in enumerate(sentence) if c==']']
>>> [sentence[i:j] for i,j in zip(start, end)]
['come', 'joy']
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to get text from second [] is to use regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.findall(r'\[.*\].*\[(.*)\]',s)
>>> a
['joy']
>>> a[0]
'joy'
>>>
```

If you want to use string indexes only, then you can do it as John1024 answered.

```
#Get indexes of [
>>> b=[i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c=='[']
>>> b
[0, 9]
>>>

#Get indexes for ]
>>> c=[i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c==']']
>>> c
[5, 13]
>>>

#Get values
>>> s[b[1]+1:c[1]]
'joy'
>>>
```

You can find more information on re module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).