# Find a matched string and print the words after

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with a bunch of random text inside. How would I go about finding the following string in the text file using regex and python.

```
name: "here's my string"
```

Basically, I want to find "here's my string" without the quotes if possible using regex and python. I would need to use regex because the string itself and the position of the string could change over time.

Match I'm looking for:

```
here's my string
```

I tried:

```
("name:([^,]+|\S+)"
```

but I don't get any results back. 
If someone could help explain where I went wrong that would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using regex? why not just split? ala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring/12572391#12572391

Comment: This is what your pattern matches:  "name" followed by a colon, followed by **either** (one or more characters that are not comma's) **OR** (one or more non-whitespace characters). Using an online regex tester, like https://regex101.com/, makes it easy to test patterns

Comment: Show us how you use your pattern and how you retreive the match results.

Comment: i try with your regex and it did works for me, i am using `re.search("name:([^,]+|\S+)", s).group(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
the_string = 'name: "here\'s my string"'
s = re.findall('"(.*?)"', the_string)[0]
```

Output:

```
"here's my string"
```