# how to split string after certain character in python

Tags: python, substring

If I have a string, lets just say, `b a hello b Hi`, how could I split the string by all `b`s **AFTER** the first occurrence of the letter `a`?

As in, it would return `["b a hello", "Hi"]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a string after a specific substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/how-to-get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is documented here: [str.rsplit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)

```
sentence = 'b a hello b Hi'
sentence.rsplit('b', 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you note the location of the gate (first 'a') then you can split the string after that point like:

### Code:

```
a_string = 'b a hello b Hi'

first_a = a_string.index('a')
a_split = a_string[first_a:].split('b')
a_split[0] = a_string[:first_a] + a_split[0]
a_split = [x.strip() for x in a_split]

print(a_split)
```

#### Result:

```
['b a hello', 'Hi']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:-**

```
a = "b a hello b Hi"
x = [x for x,y in enumerate(a) if y=='b']
ls = [a[x[0]:x[-1]],a[x[-1]+1:].strip()]
print(ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'b a hello b Hi'
print(str[str.index('a'):].split('b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "b a hello b Hi"
res = str[str.find("a"):].split("b")
res[0] = str[:str.find("a")] + res[0]
print res  
# ['b a hello ', ' Hi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
s = 'b a hello b Hi'
i = s.index("a")
s2 = s[i+1:].strip()
l = s2.split(" b ")
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example result you split the string by ' b ' so I'm going to use that.

```
a = "b a hello b Hi"
index = a.index('a') + a[a.index('a'):].index(' b ') # That's the index of first ' b '.

# Since split will give 1 empty element at the beginning I exclude that.
result = [a[:index]] + a[index:].split(' b ')[1:] 
# ['b a hello', 'Hi']
```

If you want to split by 'b' then replace them.