# Finding a word after a specific word in Python using regex from text file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm very new to regex and I need to read in from a text file and find a word after a particular word + characters. For example, the content of the text file is:

Weather now  : Mildly-sunny34
Weather tomorrow  : Cloudy

I want to extract `"Mildly-sunny34"` after searching for the keyword `"Weather now"` from the text doc. I want to make sure I do not also get `":"` or `" "` spaces apart from the word `"Mildly-sunny34"`.

Any help with some explanation is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It will help you https://regex101.com/r/dxds0B/1

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring for two reasons: (a) That question is asking about getting the remainder of the string after a given word, not an identified substring, and (b) This question is specifically asking how to accomplish the task with regex; only two answers of that question use regexs, and they use them in a way that doesn't work for this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do it:

```
import re

# Open the file for reading
with open('file.txt') as fd:

    # Iterate over the lines
    for line in fd:

        # Capture one-or-more characters of non-whitespace after the initial match
        match = re.search(r'Weather now : (\S+)', line)

        # Did we find a match?
        if match:
            # Yes, process it
            weather = match.group(1)
            print('weather: {}'.format(weather))
```

Since what you're capturing is non-whitespace that is delimited by whitespace, you can just use `\S+`.

- `\S` is non-whitespace--the opposite of `\s`, which is whitespace
- `+` indicates one or more of the previous character or character class

For the capture groups, group 0 corresponds to the entire regex and the captured subgroups are indexed sequentially. Since we only have one subgroup, we want group 1.

Running the above:

```
$ python extract.py 
weather: Mildly-sunny34
```

Comment: Hi yes! Thanks that works with a string. However I'm having an error (TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object) when I'm trying to use the text in my text file, not sure why?

Comment: I updated it to read from a file.

Comment: thanks a lot, learnt something new today :)

Comment: Your welcome. If you feel this acceptably answers your question, please close it by clicking the checkmark on the left. Thanks.