# get everything in a string after a specific symbol in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

Hi I would like to get everything after the '_' using regex

For example: I have --> I want

```
'aaa_bbb_ccc' --> 'bbb_ccc'
'dd_aaaa_1' --> 'aaaa_1'
'*/_2d*_//' --> '2d*_//'
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'aaa_bbb_ccc'.split('_', 1)[1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a string after a specific substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring)

Comment: Many thanks but i would like to do it using regex. I know how to do using split.

Comment: @FAD It's probably best to show that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather like the `split` suggestion given by @Maroun in a comment above.  Here is an option using `re.sub`:

```
x = "aaa_bbb_ccc"
output = re.sub(r'^[^_]+_', '', x)
print(output)

bbb_ccc
```

The regex does not require much explanation, and it just removes all content up to, and including, the first underscore in the input string.

Comment: Thanks. Tbh I asked because I am trying to get better with regex but in fact i m struggling with this.

Comment: @FAD Next time you ask, make sure to include your current Python script.  Had you done this, you probably would not have been downvoted.  Nothing at all wrong with asking for help it you need it :-)