# Get a substring starting from a substring, and with limited length

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know how I can get a substring from a string using index, but I want a substring starting from a substring, and with limited length.

For example. I have the string:

```
7F4P_gmLYIQottr9LMsJ5_arena_word2_fdsfds_fdsfds_fgdgdfs
```

I want to get a substring starting from the word `arena`, but no more than 40 characters. The result should be:

```
arena_word2_fdsfds_fdsfd
```

The underscores, "_", are in a way random generated, so I can't just split after the second underscore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a string after a specific substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
word = "7F4P_gmLYIQottr9LMsJ5_arena_word2_fdsfds_fdsfds_fgdgdfs"

result = "arena" + word.split("arena")[-1] #append the word "arena" and the characters after the word "arena"

limit_result = result[:40] #limit the result to 40 characters
```

Final result : "arena_word2_fdsfds_fdsfds_fgdgdfs"