# python remove string from string given location

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of IDs that I wish to extract, specifically for ID the intermediate values.

For example, the 1st ID is : garden/trade.FX.fwd/nyk12523adn

I wish to remove the values 'garden/', and '/nky12523adn', perhaps using string.replace()...

How might I do that efficiently? The starting logic would be to

1. string.find('/'), to get the location
2. then remove the prefix for the first '/', and suffix for the 2nd '/'

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a string after a specific substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `.split()` method

> The split() method splits a string into a list.
>
> You can specify the separator, default separator is any whitespace.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> string.split(separator, maxsplit)
> ```

```
id = "garden/trade.FX.fwd/nyk12523adn"
print (id.split('/')[1])
```

output:

```
trade.FX.fwd
```

if you want to use `.find()` function:

```
id = "garden/trade.FX.fwd/nyk12523adn"

idx_start = id.find('/') # find index of first '/'
idx_end = id.find('/',idx_start + 1) # find index of second '/'

print (id[idx_start+1:idx_end]) # use list slicing
```

output :

```
trade.FX.fwd
```