# How to write XPath to text before some text?

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am using temporary emails for my selenium project but I've been stuck on this issue for some time. The information always seems to be changing and I cannot figure out how I'm supposed to write it. This is the HTML:

```
<a href="https://temp-mail.org/en/view/cd89ea25d93a2fed0d182d9d8225b5b" title="" class="viewLink title-subject" data-mail-id="cd89ea25d93a2fed0d182d9d82425b5b">812479 is your Instagram code</a>
```

I've tried to find the mail-id using various methods that I've read about.

```
execute = browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "data-mail-id"]') #Attempt 1
execute = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Instagram"]')
```

I've even copied the full xpath but it always returns `Unable to Locate Element` However, the `data-mail-id` and the code changes every time you send an email to your inbox. What do I need to change?

I want the string (`"812479"`) that's followed by `" is your Instagram code"`.

Comment: The only things that change are the id and the code

Comment: Note that the class is not `data-mail-id` but `viewLink title-subject` and the text() is not `Instagram` but `812479 is your Instagram code`. Maybe you need `contains()`?

Comment: So would it be something like `//*[contains(text(), "is your Instagram code")]` ?

Comment: What if I found the best answer to my question ?

Comment: If it differs substantially from the answers received, then you should post and accept it.  If it's substantially similar to one of the posted answer, then accept the posted answer and optionally comment on how you adjusted it to fit your needs.  The goal is to help future readers while crediting those who've helped you via accepts and upvotes as you feel reflect contributions and helpfulness.

Answer (score 3):

### Straight XPath 1.0

This XPath expression,

```
substring-before(//a[contains(.,' is your Instagram code')][1], 
                 ' is your Instagram code')
```

will return the substring before `' is your Instagram code'` in the first `a` element that contains that string, or the empty string if no such element exists.

---

### XPath in Selenium

You can select the `a` element via XPath in Selenium,

```
a = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,' is your Instagram code')][1]")
```

Then [access the element's text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20996392/290085) via `a.text` and [use `split()` to implement `substring-before()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12572362/290085) (link shows *after*, but technique is easily adapted to *before*).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance because I don't really use selenium but was this the format you were talking about? `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,' is your Instagram code')][1], ' is your Instagram code'")`

Comment: Answer updated to address Selenium follow-up comment.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong? When I get the confirmation email, I `sleep(60)` just to make sure the element is fully loaded in. I then run `a = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,' is your Instagram code')][1]")` but it still says element is Unable to be Located

Comment: Back off the complexity of the XPath until you prove that something's working.   See, for example, if you can get any `a` via `//a`.  Then add back simple filters until you build up to working code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using exepected_conditions to avoid timing issues between the page loading and the script execution.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

myec = EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), "is your Instagram code")]'))

# search for the element on the page until found or TimeoutException is raised
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
myelement = wait.until(myec, "Could not find Instagram Code")
```