# Is there a way to find which word is after a certain word in a string?

Tags: python, string

We can check if a certain word/sentence is in a string by doing `if "the example word" in string` but I also want to find out the group of words that are after that word that we just found out, for example if

```
string = "The earth is shaped like Big Chungus"
```

Suppose I want to find out the series of words that are after "The", then how would I approach doing it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please add tags to specify which language you're using

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a string after a specific substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/how-to-get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this in python.

Say u have the string as follows:

```
string = "The earth is shaped like Big Chungus"
```

You can use the `split` method to cast the words in the list:

```
a=string.split()
print(a)
```

`a` will be as follows:

```
['The', 'earth', 'is', 'shaped', 'like', 'Big', 'Chungus']
```

Say you want to get all the words after a particular word you can use `list slicing` in combination with `join` keyword. In this case, you want to get all the words after `The` you can do as follows:

```
print(' '.join(a[1:]))
```

This will give output as follows:

```
earth is shaped like Big Chungus
```