# How to substring with specific start and end positions where a set of characters appear?

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, substring

I am trying to clean the data I scraped from their links. I have over 100 links in a CSV I'm trying to clean.

This is what a link looks like in the CSV:

```
"https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.somenewswebsite.com/news/society/new-covid-variant-decline-across-the-nation/014465428&ct=ga&cd=SldisGkopisopiasenjA6Y28Ug&usg=AFQjaskdfYJkasKugowe896fsdgfsweF"
```

I've observed that scraping this for HTML data doesn't go well and I have to get the URL present inside this.
I want to get the substring which starts with `&url=` and ends at `&ct` as that's where the real URL resides.

I've read posts like this but couldn't find one for ending str too. I've tried an approach from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/how-to-get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring) using the `substring` package but it doesn't work for more than one character.

How do I do this? Preferably without using third party packages?

Comment: how about `urllib.parse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand problem

If you have string then you can use string- functions like `.find()` and slice `[start:end]`

```
text = "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.somenewswebsite.com/news/society/new-covid-variant-decline-across-the-nation/014465428&ct=ga&cd=SldisGkopisopiasenjA6Y28Ug&usg=AFQjaskdfYJkasKugowe896fsdgfsweF"

start = text.find('url=') + len('url=')
end   = text.find('&ct=')

text[start:end]
```

But it may have `url=` and `ct=` in different order so better search first `&` after `url=`

```
text = "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.somenewswebsite.com/news/society/new-covid-variant-decline-across-the-nation/014465428&ct=ga&cd=SldisGkopisopiasenjA6Y28Ug&usg=AFQjaskdfYJkasKugowe896fsdgfsweF"

start = text.find('url=') + len('url=')
end   = text.find('&', start)

text[start:end]
```

---

**EDIT:**

There is also standard module `urllib.parse` to work with url - to split or join it.

```
text = "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.somenewswebsite.com/news/society/new-covid-variant-decline-across-the-nation/014465428&ct=ga&cd=SldisGkopisopiasenjA6Y28Ug&usg=AFQjaskdfYJkasKugowe896fsdgfsweF"

import urllib.parse

url, query = urllib.parse.splitquery(text)
data       = urllib.parse.parse_qs(query)

data['url'][0]
```

In `data` you have dictionary

```
{'cd': ['SldisGkopisopiasenjA6Y28Ug'],
 'ct': ['ga'],
 'rct': ['j'],
 'sa': ['t'],
 'url': ['https://www.somenewswebsite.com/news/society/new-covid-variant-decline-across-the-nation/014465428'],
 'usg': ['AFQjaskdfYJkasKugowe896fsdgfsweF']}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Python shows warning that `splitquery()` is `deprecated as of 3.8` and code should use `urlparse()`

```
text = "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.somenewswebsite.com/news/society/new-covid-variant-decline-across-the-nation/014465428&ct=ga&cd=SldisGkopisopiasenjA6Y28Ug&usg=AFQjaskdfYJkasKugowe896fsdgfsweF"

import urllib.parse

parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(text)
data  = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parts.query)

data['url'][0]
```

Comment: I don't know for some reason I thought there would be a more elegant way. But if it works, it works :)

Comment: as for me it is elegant. But I also added example with `urlib.parse`